# How to find details about function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if $\frac{df} {dx}= \frac{df}{dy}$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

I am trying assignment questions of real analysis and I was unable to solve this question. In fact, I don't have any idea on how to start.

So, I am looking for help here.

> Let $f$  be a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\frac{df} {dx}= \frac{df}{dy}$ for all $(x,y)\in  \mathbb{R}^2$. Now which of the following options are true:

1 $f$ is constant on all lines parallel to the line $x=-y$.

2 $f(x,y)=0 \quad\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

3 $f(x,y)=f(-y,x) \quad\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

4 $f(x,y)-f(y,x)=(x-y) \frac {df}{dx}(x*,y*) + (y-x) \frac {df}{dy} (x*,y*) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I am unable to get any idea on how to use the hypothesis $\frac{df} {dx}= \frac{df}{dy}$ to deduce or contradict  any of the options.

I studied multivariable calculus from Tom M Apostol in case it is of any help.

Please help me. Kindly just give outlines not complete solution.

Comment: If $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ I think the correct notation in the hypothesis is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Comment: @АлександрПальма: The notation is only (meaningfully) different when there is composition of functions. Typically when the position coordinates are implied as functions of time. For example, the function $x(t)+y(t)+z(t)+t$ cares about partial vs total.

Comment: Option 1 seems the opposite: it should be $y=x$. That version of option 1 contradicts 2 and 3. What does the star notation in option 4 mean?

Comment: @АлександрПальма Ya but I don't know how to type that. I am a new user. So, used which I knew to type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_x=f_y$, then for every $c\in \mathbb R$,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(t,c-t)=f_x(t,c-t)-f_y(t,c-t)=0.
$$
Hence $f$ is constant on the set
$$
L_c=\{(t,c-t):t\in\mathbb R\},
$$
which represents the parametric expression of the straight line
$$
x+y=c.
$$
Thus $f$ has to be of the form
$$
f(x,y)=g(x+y).
$$
To understand that, observe first that $\mathbb R^2=\bigcup_{c\in\mathbb R}L_c$, and in particular, note that $\,(x,y)\in L_{x+y}$.

As $f$ is constant on every $L_c$, then for every $c\in\mathbb R$, there exists a function $g$, such that
$$
f(x,y)=g(c), \quad \text{for all $(x,y)\in L_c$}.
$$
But $c=x+y$, for all $(x,y)\in L_c$, and hence $\,f(x,y)=g(c)=g(x+y)$.

Comment: Why "Thus f has to be of the form f(x,y)=g(x+y)." How did you deduced that? Also ,It's my humble request to you to illuminate on option 3 and 4

Comment: Can you please reply me?

Comment: @Avenger See my improved answer.

Comment: So, 1,4 are true and 2,3 are false. Am I right?

Comment: @Avenger YES both 1 and 4 are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat more *geometric* explanation of @Yiorgos or @Ted-Shrifin answers.

$f$ satisfies a first order partial differential equation. This equation says something about a directional derivative, namely that the derivative in the direction $ (-1,1)^t $ is 0. To make things clear, we can change variables so the direction $(-1,1)^t$ is a coordinate direction. There are many ways of doing this, for example:
$ (x,y) = u*(-1,1) + v*(1,0) $

i.e.: $x = -u + v$ and $y = u$.

The inverse transformation is $u = y$, $v=x+y$. Think of $f$ as a function of points, that can be written in terms of different coordinate systems. To avoid confusion, let $f^*$ be $f$ in the new coordinates. Explicitly:

$ f^*(u,v) = f(-u + v, u)$

And so, $f(x,y) = f^*(y, x+y)$

Then:

$ \frac{\partial f^*}{\partial u}(u,v) = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(-u+v,v) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(-u+v,v) = 0$

an equation which is easy to solve: $f^*$ is a function of *v* only (constant in $u$):
$f^*(u,v) = h(v)$ for some function $h$ (for example $h(v) = f^*(0,v)$ ), and going back to the original coordinates: $f(x,y) = f^*(y,x+y) = h(x+y)$.

So, 1) is true, 2) and 3) are false (they may hold for *some* solution of the PDE, but not for *all* solutions), and (assuming (x*,y*) means an intermediate point between (x,y) and (y,x)) 4) is also true (the expressions at both sides of the equation are both 0).

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of $f$ is parallel to $\vec i + \vec j$, so level curves are orthogonal to that constant vector. That makes lines $x+y=c$ the level curves, so $f(x,y) = g(x+y)$ for any differentiable function $g$.

Comment: Shriffin How is gradient Of f parallel to i^+ j^?

Comment: Write down the definition of the gradient and use what you were given.

Answer (score -1):

Since $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, then we must have $$\nabla f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$$ Therefore $$\nabla f= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,1)$$ and the gradient can be written as $$\nabla f= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{j}$$ This the direction of steepest ascent is along all lines parallel to the vector $\vec{i}+\vec{j}$ Now the gradient is always normal (perpendicular) to the level curves, so this means all lines parallel to $\vec{i}-\vec{j}$ are level curves, that is $f$ is constant along all lines of the forms $x+y= c$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Now use that info to make a determination concerning #$3$

Comment: Can you please help me In 3, 4 options?

Comment: I think 1 is true, 2 false . But I don't know how to approach C and D